# How to create a hint window to show gif and close the window after several seconds?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to write an extension of vscode. I need to show a gif somewhere. I see the hint on a variable of vscode is a window, is there an API to create such a window? Or is there other ways to create a window and close it after several seconds?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to show it in a *window*, but you could show it in an *editor tab* - more specifically, a [webview](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/webview). The default webview sample on that page even uses gif files. Since a webview simply renders HTML, you can use a regular `<img>` tag for this.

To close it again after 4 seconds, you can use `setTimeout()` with a callback that invokes [`WeviewPanel.dispose()`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#WebviewPanel.dispose).